# Wildcard query in solr returns unexpected results

Tags: solr

I executed this query in Solr-5.5.3

> id:{2022-0303-01-000001 TO 2023-0305*}

And these are values in solr

> id
>  2022-0303-01-000001
> 2022-0303-01-000002
>  2022-0303-01-000003
> 2022-0303-01-000004
>  2022-0303-01-000005
> 2022-0304-01-000001
>  2022-0304-01-000002
> 2022-0304-01-000003
>  2022-0304-01-000004
> 2023-0303-01-000001
>  2023-0304-01-000001

In my expectation results would be exactly same as I specified.
However, a few record didn't appear.

All I got:

> id
>  2022-0303-01-000002
>  2022-0303-01-000003
> 2022-0303-01-000004
>  2022-0303-01-000005
> 2022-0304-01-000001
>  2022-0304-01-000002
> 2022-0304-01-000003
>  2022-0304-01-000004

Missing(these 2 record also should be in results):

> 2023-0303-01-000001
>  2023-0304-01-000001

Range-search in solr doesn't work if field-type is string? Please help.

Comment: can you try with id:{2022-0303-01-000001 TO 2023-03*}

Comment: What is the field type you're querying?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti
I tried and it returned same results as I posted

Comment: @MatsLindh
Field-type is String , it's a primary key

Comment: Is that query suitable? I mean whether it is corret in the point of syntax.

Comment: The `*` is probably not doing anything good, so drop that at least (since wildcards doesn't really make sense for range searches).